# Google Cloud Platform instance creation failure (Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[1].initializeParams.diskSizeGb')

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, ssd, nvme

I'm trying to create an instance using GCP. The followings are the specifications (the rest of the settings are set as default):

```
Region: us-west1-b
GPU type: NVIDIA Tesla V100
Number of GPUs: 1
Series: N1
Machine type: Custom (12 vCPUs, 64GB memory)
Booting disk: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS balanced persistent disk 50GB
Add local SSD: 16 NVMes (Each SSD is 375GB, so total of 375GB * 16 = 6000GB)
```

It seems that adding the local SSDs is making problem. The error message says:

```
Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[1].initializeParams.diskSizeGb': '6000'. Invalid local SSD size in GB: 6000
```

However, I don't understand why it is impossible to create this instance. When I googled for the error message, there is not much to tell. Is there any clue what that error message indicates, and how I can fix it?

Comment: It says exactly what is wrong? ‘6000’ Invalid disk size. I’m not very familiar with google cloud. But 16 locally attached disks available on a cloud instance sounds pretty unlikely. Have you checked the limits? This all seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Appleoddity Actually, if I attempt to create an instance with 2 SSDs (375GB * 2 = 750GB), it will return the same error. I don't understand why they've made multiple SSD options available if they are going to return an error if I attempt to attach more than one SSD.

Comment: I’ve researched this and don’t see documentation that says to specify storage size with Local SSD disks. It’s not clear in your post (to the untrained eye) if you are using the UI or CLI to do this. You should update your post with exactly what steps you’re doing, including any commands or code you use because obviously the problem here is how you’re doing that. Back to my previous comment I found that 16 local SSD disks is valid for N1 instance types. So it’s not a limitation of Google, it’s a problem with how you’re defining the instance.

Comment: @Appleoddity I was using the console, I admit that I've lacked some details in the question about this. Thanks for pointing this out. As your suggestion, I've tried to create the instance using the CLI command, and posted the answer according to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Appleoddity who left a great comment and @Goli Nikitha who answered [my question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71732483/google-cloud-platform-instance-creation-failure-invalid-value-for-field-resour), I've figured this out using the CLI command instead of the console. I still don't know why the console does not work, but I will share the CLI command that I've used to fix this.

`gcloud compute instances create <INSTANCE_NAME> --project=<PROJECT_NAME> --zone=us-west1-b --machine-type=custom-12-65536 --network-interface=network-tier=PREMIUM,subnet=default --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE --service-account=<SERVICE_ACCOUNT> --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append --accelerator=count=1,type=nvidia-tesla-v100 --create-disk=auto-delete=yes,boot=yes,device-name=<INSTANCE_NAME>,image=projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20220331a,mode=rw,size=50,type=projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/zones/us-west1-b/diskTypes/pd-balanced --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --no-shielded-secure-boot --shielded-vtpm --shielded-integrity-monitoring --reservation-affinity=any`